# Remove a single PHP extension

Tags: php, linux, centos

I have PHP 5.3 running, but for few reasons I am trying to remove `php-libxml` from the php modules.

Is it possible to do this? Or else I need to recompile and install the PHP again from scratch without including the mentioned PHP module?

Comment: tried asking in server fault..?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-disable-entity-loader.php

Comment: @Bagus Tesa : Haven't added in serverfault. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @anshuVersatile : But actually its centos and i have installed it directly from repo using yum install.

Comment: centos is crazy about installation (personnaly experienced) for what i tride to recompile php

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu you could try (from command line):

```
phpdismod libxml
```

(or `php5dismod libxml`depending of your installation)

Comment: #rap-2-h : Thanks for the reply. But its centos 6.8. Not sure whether any command line single command options are available for this.